# Protractor Reusbale Function for boundary value analysis

Tags: protractor

is there any smart solution/reusable function to test the boundary value analyis..

for example : test the email text box accepting @ ,A-Z , a-z , .com, .org etc

firsnt name txt box should accept all charactor ,utf-8 characters set and max and.min length ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to get random strings of your preferred length(for first name)

For email id, use the same function twice by concatenating @ between two functions.

```
this.getRandomString = function randomString(length, chars) {
        var mask = '';
        if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
        if (chars.indexOf('!') > -1) mask += '~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";\'<>?,./|\\';
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += mask[Math.floor(Math.random() * mask.length)];
        return result;
    };
```